# Selenium just opens up chromedriver and doesnt do antyhing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've installed chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads I've installed latest version **120.0.6099.109**

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Uncomment for headless mode

# Initialize the WebDriver with the Service
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

try:
    # Navigate to a webpage
    driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk/')

    # Perform your interactions here
    print(driver.title)

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```

For some reason every time I run the script the browser opens up, but nothing happens after sometime I get the error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01256EE3+174339]
    (No symbol) [0x01180A51]
    (No symbol) [0x00E96FF6]
    (No symbol) [0x00EBA756]
    (No symbol) [0x00EB7A0F]
    (No symbol) [0x00EEE259]
    (No symbol) [0x00EEDBBA]
    (No symbol) [0x00EE6DA6]
    (No symbol) [0x00EC1034]
    (No symbol) [0x00EC1F8D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012F4B1C+820540]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013B53EE+653550]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013B4E09+652041]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013A97CC+605388]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013B5D9B+656027]
    (No symbol) [0x0118FE6C]
    (No symbol) [0x011883B8]
    (No symbol) [0x011884DD]
    (No symbol) [0x01175818]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75BC7BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x76EDBD2B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x76EDBCAF+191]
```